# PDF file gets corrupted if data is acquired through $http.get() but remains intact if acquired through $http.post() in Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-post, http-get, node-rest-client

Recently I have a faced a peculiar problem while doing some development involving some interaction with Node Web-API and AngularJS front-end application. I have written an NodeJS Web-API that hits another ASP.NET Web Service and gets some pdf data. Which does the job quite well.

[image]

From the picture we can easily see that it responds while being hit as a post call from the front end. Though it just serves data to the calling application, I have made it a **POST** API because if I do the same things in a **GET** API the file served to the front-end calling application get a corrupted PDF file with bigger size.
Why $http.get() call gets corrupted data when $http.post() gets the file intact?
Can anyone have in-depth idea about it?